# Join sum from same date

Tags: php, mysql, date, join, sum

How do I join sums (dollar) from the same date and present them by date in MySQL and PHP?

[image: My table looks like this]

ID = auto_increment

I wan't the result to be like this

```
2012-01-14 - 48
2012-02-21 - 19
2012-02-25 - 31
2012-03-01 - 11
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` is what you should be searching for.

Comment: Is this homework? It's formatted like homework...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT date, SUM(dollar)
  FROM tableName
 GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `DATE`, SUM(`DOLLAR`) FROM your_table GROUP BY `DATE`;
```

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php